# Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' Error

Tags: php, string, wordpress

This is the line it's referencing:

```
$html = '<div class="devider"><a id="back-top" class="top" href="#top">'.$atts["title"].'</a></div><hr />';
```

Using wordpress 4.1 and PHP 5.5

Just moved my site to a new how and this error was showing up on a few pages:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in /mydomain/wp-content/themes/mytheme/include/short_code.php on line 105

Comment: `var_dump($atts);`  what is in it? sho us please

Answer (score 1):

I had the warnings for members.php

In many places my code had this:

```
if($a['search'] !== false and $a['search'] !== 'false') {
            $r .= $this->search();
        }
I had to change it to this to remove the warning:
if(isset($a['search']) !== false and isset($a['search']) !== 'false') {
            $r .= $this->search();
        }
```

BUT then I lost my search box so instead of Not equal in the first part of the expression, I changed it to is equal (took away the !):

```
if(isset($a['search']) == false and isset($a['search']) !== 'false') {
$r .= $this->search();
}
I had to also change a line that looked like:
$this->list = $a['list'];
```

to:

```
$this->list = isset($a['list']);
```

Hope this will helpful..

Comment: Thanks for your comment Sandesh, I'm not sure what this all means, I did however realize something. Every time I used this horizontal line  shortcode "[cs_divider]" that's how many times that error text would appear. For example, the page had 5 of those lines than that error text appeared 5 times. Any advice?